# PWA - Set Splash Screen for android device

Tags: android, css, meta-tags, progressive-web-apps

I have one responsive website which I want to use as a progressive web app. I have initialized basic things like setting up icons, App name etc. Everything is working fine just the issue is with the splash screen. On the iOS devices, I'm able to change the splash screen with below code.

`<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" media="(device-width: 375px) and (device-height: 812px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3)" href="<?= \yii\helpers\Url::to('@web/img/splash/iPhone-X.png') ?>">`

But on the Android device I', not able to do so. My actual requirement is to display the logo only on the splash screen. On Android it is displaying the logo and app name as well on the splash screen.

Below is my `manifest.json` file. **I've searched on Google and Stack Overflow and none of the results helped me that is why I have to post a question on Stack Overflow.**

```
{
"short_name": "MyApp",
"name": "My Progressive App",
"icons": [
    {
        "src": "/img/splash/48x48.png",
        "type": "image/png",
        "sizes": "48x48"
    },
    {
        "src": "/img/splash/96x96.png",
        "type": "image/png",
        "sizes": "96x96"
    },
    {
        "src": "/img/splash/144x144.png",
        "type": "image/png",
        "sizes": "144x144"
    },
    {
        "src": "/img/splash/192x192.png",
        "type": "image/png",
        "sizes": "192x192"
    },
    {
        "src": "/img/splash/256x256.png",
        "type": "image/png",
        "sizes": "256x256"
    },
    {
        "src": "/img/splash/384x384.png",
        "type": "image/png",
        "sizes": "384x384"
    },
    {
        "src": "/img/splash/512x512.png",
        "type": "image/png",
        "sizes": "512x512"
    }
],
"background_color": "#FFFFFF",
"display": "standalone",
"theme_color": "#FFFFFF"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your problem is to display only the icon without the name of the app on Android, it is unfortunately not possible, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

To show the app icon when you `Add to homescreen` just make sure you provide the following links in your template:

```
<link rel="icon" sizes="192x192" href="nice-highres.png"> (recommended)
<link rel="icon" sizes="128x128" href="niceicon.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="128x128" href="niceicon.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="128x128" href="niceicon.png">
```

Your `manifest.json` looks fine, just add `192x192` icon there also, as it is the recommended icon size.

Comment: I'm having an issue with the splash screen not the icon.

Comment: Then, you can remove the name property from the manfiest.json